# Error "HTML tag 'ul' requires an end tag FIREventNames.h"

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image: FIREventNames.h]

I created a new single view application (Objective-C) and just did pop init, install, etc, which is a procedure in Firebase homepage.

Finally, I wrote `[FIRApp configure]; application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in `AppDelegate.m`.

And when I build this project, this error came out with this message. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: here is my capture image : http://postimg.org/image/5y54k7tm5/

Answer (score 5):

There is something wrong in XCode when reading {@link} inside html tags. You can turn off the setting 'Build Settings->Warning - All languages -> Documentation Comments' to circumvent this issue.

Comment: Also seeing the same with Xcode 8.3.2 when something like `{@code xyz}` is between my tags. I've seen this with `ul`, `dl` and `table` elements. Replacing with use of back ticks for code works but there's clearly not a clean equivalent to fix the case for links.